# Safari Website Notifications in Python

Tags: python, safari, apple-push-notifications, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to integrate Apple's new Safari Website Push Notifications. The client side part works ok. Same for part of the server side. When it comes to actually sending the notification, nothing is received.

No much to debug. I'm running Django 1.4 and using https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs. Unlike the iOS Push Notifs, in Safari Push Notifs the payload has a few new fields.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The payload structure is very unflexible and Apple's Docs don't mention this. The url_args field is mandatory and should reflect the number of variables you put inside website.json, under urlFormatString.

Comment: Hello, I'm faced similar problem now, can you please post code snippet you've used, because I can't create proper payload

Answer (score 0):

may be like this-

```
payload = Payload(alert={
                    "title": "",
                    "body": "",
                }, sound="default", badge=1,url_arg={"name":"https://www.epush.in",},)
```